# Structural time series model with multiplicative error term

Tags: kalman-filters, r

I have a noisy time series measurement of a biological signal which I need to smoothen. I believe that the error of the measurement is proportional to the signal strength. I am currently working in R and managed to smoothen the signal using `ts`, `STructTS` and `tsSmooth`:

```
ts_raw_data <- ts(raw_data, start=0)
struct_raw_data <- StructTS(ts_raw_data, type="trend")
smoothened_data <- tsSmooth(struct_raw_data)[, c("level")]
```

However, according to the documentation, `StructTS` uses an additive error term:

> The simplest model is the local level model specified by type =
>   "level". This has an underlying level m[t] which evolves by
>
> *m[t+1] = m[t] + xi[t], xi[t] ~ N(0, σ^2_ξ)*
>
> The observations are
>
> *x[t] = m[t] + eps[t], eps[t] ~ N(0, σ^2_\eps)*

Instead, I think I need a model where the observations are modelled as:

> *x[t] = m[t] * eps[t], eps[t] ~ N(1, σ^2*\eps)_

Ideally, I would like to solve this problem in R, but Python, Matlab or Julia would also work. Do you have any suggestions how to achieve that?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP. Do you have additional assumptions, like: is the signal positive (like a count)? Does  the noise + signal observation remain positive? Do they have other properties?

Comment: Hi: You could take the log of $x_t$ to turn into additive. Also, you can use the DLM package in R but, since you're transforming  it to log, you'll need to be careful when implementing it.

Comment: @Paul: Thinking about this some more, you can make that transformation but you're still going to have non-linearity in the observation equation so I think this is going to require the extended kalman filter. I'm not familar with a package in R that handles the extended KF but I'm sure there must be one on cran.

Comment: Paul: At a galnce, this looks useful for implement the extended KF in R. http://blogs2.datall-analyse.nl/2016/02/15/rcode_extended_kalman_filter_maximum_likelihood/#more-36

Comment: @LaurentDuval: Thank you for your response. The signal is positive and the observation (noise+signal) is also positive. I know that this is not strictly compatible with a multiplicative Gaussian error.
I am looking at protein abundance (as measured via immunofluorescence) in a cell. Proteins are produced from mRNA and protein half life is roughly 3 times longer than mRNA half life. mRNAs are considered to be negative binomial distributed. Still, the longer protein half life does some averaging. So according to the central limit theorem, I would assume proteins are gaussian distributed.

Comment: @markleeds: Thank you for suggesting to transform the variable. Unfortunately the example in the link you provided uses difference equations as state transition functions. In my case I do not know the difference equations. Therefore I think I should use
`m[t+1] = m[t] + xi[t], xi[t] ~ N(0, σ^2_ξ)`
or the local linear trend model, type = "trend", with the same measurement equation, but with a time-varying slope in the dynamics for m[t], given by
`m[t+1] = m[t] + n[t] + xi[t], xi[t] ~ N(0, σ^2_ξ)`
`n[t+1] = n[t] + ζ[t], ζ[t] ~ N(0, σ^2_ζ)`

Comment: Hi Paul: I was only sending the example to show how the extended KF works rather than to suggest that you should use their model. The local linear trend model is straightforward but I thought you wanted a multiplicative model ? if you take the log of the system equation, you end up ( I think ) with y_t = exp(x_t) + error term as the obervation equation. This is the non-linearity but I'm pretty sure it's amenable to the EKF. If the example  I sent isn't good, I would google for "Extended Kalman Filter in R".  I don't have any experience with EKF but your case doesn't seem terribly complicated.